# Can't get email or public profile facebook by ASP MVC5

Tags: facebook, oauth, asp.net-mvc-5

I use MVC5 to get public profile user, but I just get ID and DisplayName of user. I have researched multi ways but have no result. This my setup snippet:

```
var options = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AppId = "xxx",
            AppSecret = "xxx",
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "ExternalCookie",
            Provider = new FacebookAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnAuthenticated = async context =>
                {
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
                }
            }
        };
        options.Scope.Add("email");
        options.Scope.Add("public_profile");
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(options);
```

And I call request result in action

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var userDisplayModel = new UserDisplayModel();

        var authenticateResult = await AuthenticationManager.AuthenticateAsync("ExternalCookie");
        if (authenticateResult != null)
        {
            userDisplayModel = new UserDisplayModel()
            {
                DisplayName = authenticateResult.Identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Value
            };
        }

        return View(userDisplayModel);
    }
```

Comment: With API v2.4, Facebook reduced the number of fields that are returned by default, all additional fields now have to be specifically asked for – see their changelog. Most likely your authentication provider code will need to be adapted/modified to take that into account.

Comment: Have you find a solution yet? I have the same issue